# How to define code for different iOS versions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, deprecated

I am working on an iOS app. I want it to support iOS 7 and 8. It is going pretty nicely, however there are lots of different parts of the app which use Apple APIs. Some of these APIs work in both iOS 8 and 7. However, some of them are deprecated in iOS 8. So I therefore went to the Apple developer site to see what to replace them with (new methods/etc....).

However, I now have the problem that the app will work on iOS 8 fine, but certain parts of it don't work properly on iOS 7 as I'm trying to use an iOS 8 API...... (lol).

So I just wanted to know, what is the best way to implement code which works on iOS 8 and 7. I had a few ideas (below), but I'm not sure which is best:

**IDEA 1**

Whenever I have code which doesn't work on both OS's, I use an if function (which calls a macro) like so:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {
    // iOS 7 device. Use iOS 7 apis.
}

else {
   // iOS 8 (or higher) - use iOS 8 apis.
}
```

**IDEA 2**

I was thinking about using ifdef definitions all around the app like so:

```
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
     // iOS 8 code here....
#else
     // iOS 7 code here....
#endif
```

Which way is better? I would have thought that the second idea is much faster and uses less resources right?

Or are both my ideas rubbish? Is there a much better way about solving this problem?

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: Do not test for the iOS version. Test for the availability of the API at runtime. Read the "SDK Compatibility Guide" in the docs.

Comment: FYI - If the API is supported in iOS 7 and deprecated in iOS 8, you don't need to do anything at all. The iOS 7 API is what you should use. It will still work under iOS 8.

Comment: @rmaddy Are you sure about that. I was doing some work with reading a simple XML Plist file. In iOS 8, my code used for reading the XML file stopped working. As soon as I tested it with the iOS 8 api, it started working again as normal. Also saying that one should just stick with deprecated APIs..... that sounds dangerous, could lead to memory leaks or unexpected crashes surely.

Comment: I'm 100% sure about that. If you are having issue with a specific API, then post a question specific to that issue. This question is a bit too general to provide specific details.

Comment: Deprecated API's doesn't mean that, you shouldn't use that in current version. It means, it won't work from next version onwards, and only work till current version.

Comment: @MidhunMP Deprecated APIs do not mean that they stop working. APIs deprecated in iOS 3 still work with rare exceptions. And yes, it does mean you shouldn't use it in the version it is deprecated in unless you are also still supporting versions prior to the deprecation. In other words, deprecated in iOS 8 means if you only support iOS 8, you should move to the new API now. But if you also support iOS 7 then it's fine to keep using the deprecated API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't suggest checking the Version and writing code based on that. Instead you need to check whether that API is available or not.

For checking a class available or not:

```
Class checkClass = NSClassFromString(@"CheckingClass");

if (checkClass)
{
   // Available
}
else
{
  // Not Available
}
```

If you need to check a feature/function available;

```
if ([checkClass respondsToSelector:@selector(yourMethod:)])
{
   // Feature/ Method Available
}
else
{
   // Feature/ Method Not Available
}
```

**NOTE:**

Deprecated API's doesn't mean that you shouldn't use that in current version. It means, it won't work from next version onwards, and only work till current version.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer and example. This seems like the best way to approach the problem. Thanks once again.

Comment: The note at the end of this answer is incorrect. Deprecated APIs very rarely ever stop working.

Comment: @rmaddy: I didn't get what you mean by that. I know a tons of deprecated API's in iOS 6, that doesn't work on iOS 8

Comment: I may have over stated that a bit. It depends on the class and API. I know of APIs that were deprecated in iOS 3.0 that still work in iOS 8. But you are right, there are chunks of some deprecated APIs that stopped working quickly but that isn't always the case.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, you are correct. You can use deprecated API's as long as it exists (No version barrier)

Comment: @rmaddy But still an API becomes deprecated for a reason. If its deprecated then you are not meant to use it. You need to use the API provided for that particular OS version. Otherwise, whats the point of deprecating anything in the first place...?

Comment: @Supertecnoboff Deprecated means that support for it could be dropped in the future, eventually, maybe. It doesn't mean you can't keep using it at the moment. If you support iOS 7 and 8 then there is NOTHING wrong with using an API that was active in iOS 7 but deprecated in iOS 8. I have app store apps full of such code. When I drop iOS 7 support in the future, then I will replace those deprecated APIs.

Answer (score 2):

The `ifdef`-way won't work, because preprocessor statements are evaluated at compile-time; but only at runtime we know which ios-version we have to deal with.

You would use macros for example if you wanted to support Mac OS X and iOS with the same code, because you know at compile-time if the binary will be for Mac OS or iOS.

So you need in this case approach 1 - or, even better, you should use `respondsToSelector:` to check for availability instead of testing the iOS version if possible.

However, because you are only dealing with deprecation warnings, you don't have to do anything and should simply continue using the deprecated APIs until the app no longer needs to support ios7.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sounds good but I think I will go with @MidhunMP answer. As using deprecated APIs, doesn't fill me with confidence that my app will work without crashing.

Comment: The deprecation really is only an announcement that apple will remove it in the future (ios9) - it doesn't mean it's unstable or not supported anymore!